# I'm having difficulty in calling variables outside of one function

Tags: c#, class, static

```
using System;

namespace survey {

    static class program {

        static void Main(string[] args) {

            program.chinesezodiac();

            Console.WriteLine("\nYour name is: " + name);
            Console.WriteLine("Your age is: " + age);

            if (year == "1999") {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the rabbit");
            }

            else if (year == "2000") {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the dragon");
            }

            else if (year == "2001") {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the snake");
            }
            else if (year == "2002") {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the horse");
            }
            else if (year == "2003") {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the goat");
            }
            else if (year == "2004") {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the monkey");
            }

            else if (year == "2005") {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the rooster");
            }

            else if (year == "2006") {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the dog");
            }

            else if (year == "2007") {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the pig");
            }

            else if (year == "2008") {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the dragon");
            }

            else if (year == "2009") {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the ox");
            }

            else if (year == "2010") {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the tiger");
            }

            else {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid year");
            }
        }

        public static void chinesezodiac(string[] args) {

            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease note\nThis program is only applicable for users born between 1999 and 2010");

            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease input name > ");
            public static string name = Console.ReadLine();

            if (name == "") {
                do {
                    Console.Write("Invalid input. Please try again > ");
                    name = Console.ReadLine();
                } while ( name == "");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease input age > ");
            public static string age = Console.ReadLine();

            if (age == "") {
                do {
                    Console.Write("Invalid input. Please try again > ");
                    age = Console.ReadLine();
                } while ( age == "");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease input birth year > ");
            public static string year = Console.ReadLine();

            if (year == "") {
                do {
                    Console.Write("Invalid input. Please try again > ");
                    year = Console.ReadLine();
                } while ( year == "");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Learning everything from linkedin. I've only ever used c++. I'm having trouble getting the compiler to recognize the year. I tried making it static. i tried making the functions static. I tried looking up global variables.

I'm looking to call the chinesezodiac function at the start of the main program (i realize its not efficient, its a practice challenge part of the lesson) but when i do do that, the program doesn't compile because it doesn't recognize 'year' 'in this context'. I'm using repl.it

Comment: It is very similar to C++ in that `name`, `year`, and `age` are local variables in the `chinesezodiac` function and cannot be accessed outside that function.

Comment: "Learning everything from linkedin" - maybe you should realize that a site used for conencting professionals is no replacement for ever reading the documentation? This is really new. it is not even "blogs" or "internet", it is literally a social platform that you use for learning a language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of trying to set globally available values, what I would recommend would be to turn your name/age logic into functions you can call from Main() that return the values. For instance, you could turn your name logic into something like

```
private static string GetName()
{
  Console.WriteLine("\nPlease input name > ");
  string name = Console.ReadLine();

  if (name == "") 
  {
    do {
      Console.Write("Invalid input. Please try again > ");
      age = Console.ReadLine();
       } while ( name == "");
  }
  return name;
}
```

Then, from your Main method, you can call it like this

```
string name = GetName();
```

This is generally much more readable/maintainable than global variables, as you never know where those might be modified in other code.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for responding. I did that just now and it won't compile because "survey.program.getage() cannot declare instance members in a static class". So i removed the 'static' from the class or tired making the strings public. It still won't work.

Comment: Because the `Program` class is static the `GetName` method needs to be static as well. This can be done by adding the `static` keyword. I have made this change to the example code.